# How to use an array?

Tags: arrays

Write a Java program that stores the letters of the English alphabet as characters in an array at compile time, i.e., using an array initializer. The program should display (from the array) on separate lines
1. The entire alphabet 
2. The first six letters
3. The last ten letters 
4. The eleventh letter
5. The entire alphabet in reverse order
There should be five lines of output

Comment: You are now free to answer my homework problem.  I stand ready to award 15 points to the lucky winner :-)

Answer (score 0):

I realized shortly after writing my comment, that you might award 15 points to me.  Here is your answer:

```
char alphabet[] = {'a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g', 'h', 'i',
                   'j', 'k', 'l', 'm', 'n', 'o', 'p', 'q', 'r',
                   's', 't', 'u', 'v', 'w', 'x', 'y', 'z'};

// entire alphabet
for (int i=0; i < alphabet.length; ++i)
    System.out.print(alphabet[i] + " ");

System.out.print("\n");

// first six letters
for (int i=0; i < 6; ++i)
    System.out.print(alphabet[i] + " ");

System.out.print("\n");

// last ten letters
for (int i=alphabet.length-10; i < alphabet.length; ++i)
    System.out.print(alphabet[i] + " ");

System.out.print("\n");

// eleventh letter
System.out.println(alphabet[10]);

// entire alphabet in reverse order
for (int i=alphabet.length-1; i >= 0; --i)
    System.out.print(alphabet[i] + " ");
```